# How to create an SSIS package with a Script Component

Tags: sql-server-2008, scripting, query, ssms

I am using Microsoft **Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)** to create an **SSIS package**. Take into account that is my first attempt with SSIS.

I want to take data from a **Source database** elaborate them and put in a **Destination database**. In the elaboration task I need also data from the **Destination database**.

In the **Data Flow** I have two "objects" a Source and a Destination. In the Source I created a **query** that takes data from the Source database.

Then I added a **Script Component** between the two.

The problems that I encounter are two:

```
1) How can I call from my script the
result of the query?

2) How can I also get the data from
the destination (it allows me to
connect up to 1 arrow to the script)

3) How can I write the elaborated data in the destination?
```

I hope you can help me, because I am quite lost.